# How to calculate the first point where a line intersects a circle radius on a map, efficiently?

Tags: python, math, geopy, haversine

I am using geopy to calculate the first point where a straight line intersects a circle on a map, this code works perfectly as expected but I believe is quite inefficient as it has to compute the lat/lng of every point of the line until it reaches the circle radius.

Is there a more efficient way to do this with geopy or other similar libraries?

In the below example, the line starts at 51.137933, -0.267017 and moves in a straight direction of 257 degrees until it gets within 10.5 nautical miles of the circle center 51.053953, -0.625003

```
import math
from geopy.distance import distance as dist

# Starting position in degrees
lat1 = 51.137933
lon1 = -0.267017

target_lat = 51.053953
target_lon = -0.625003

# Direction in radians
direction = math.radians(257)

# Earth's radius in miles
R = 3963.1676

# Distance to move in miles
distance = 0.1

d = dist((lat1, lon1), (target_lat, target_lon)).nautical
last_d = d

while d > 10.5:
    # Convert latitude and longitude to radians
    lat1 = math.radians(lat1)
    lon1 = math.radians(lon1)

    # Calculate new latitude and longitude
    lat2 = math.asin(math.sin(lat1) * math.cos(distance / R) + math.cos(lat1) * math.sin(distance / R) * math.cos(direction))
    lon2 = lon1 + math.atan2(math.sin(direction) * math.sin(distance / R) * math.cos(lat1), math.cos(distance / R) - math.sin(lat1) * math.sin(lat2))

    # Convert latitude and longitude back to degrees
    lat1 = math.degrees(lat2)
    lon1 = math.degrees(lon2)

    d = dist((lat1, lon1), (target_lat, target_lon)).nautical
    if d > last_d:
        print("NOT FOUND")
        break

print(lat1, lon1)
```

Comment: A more efficient method is to solve the equations using quadratics. [Here's the maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228841/how-do-i-calculate-the-intersections-of-a-straight-line-and-a-circle) on Mathematics Stack Exchange, which could be implemented in Python. This assumes 2D, but my geometry isn't advanced enough for global geometries! Hopefully it's at least a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I fully understand your problem. but in a carthesian coordinate system, where you have 2 points **a** and **b**, you obtain a directional vector from point **a** to point **b** as **c = (b-a)**. now when you scale/normalize **c** to length 1 (that is, divide by its length) you should obtain the intersection with a circle of radius d around **a** as **a + d * c**...this should work for polar coordinates too i guess